# Explain a section of Euclid's Theorem on an infinite number of prime numbers.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm trying to understand Euclid's Theorem, using proof by contradiction, which states:

> There are an infinite number of prime numbers.

In the book it has the following explanation: We assume that there are a finite number of prime numbers, $p_1, p_2, \dotsc, p_n$. We then consider an integer $Q$:
$$Q:= p_1 \cdot p_2 \dotsb p_n+1$$

From the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic we know that any composite number can be represented as the product of various prime numbers. Therefore:

$$Q=p_1^{e_1} \cdot p_2^{e_2} \dotsb p_n^{e_n}, \ \ \text{for a suitable }e_1,\dotsc,e_n \in \mathbb{N_0}$$

Since $Q>1$, there is at least one $i \in [n]$ with $e_i \neq 0$. Therefore, for $p_i$ we have that:

$$p_i \mid Q \ \text{and} \ p_i \mid (Q-1)$$

This is a contradiction to our original assumption that $p_i \geq2$. Thus there are an infinite number of prime numbers.

I'm having difficulty understanding how the fact $p_i \mid Q \ \text{and} \ p_i \mid (Q-1)$ is used to come to the contradiction.

Comment: If a number divides two other numbers, it also divides their differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $p\mid Q$ and $p\mid(Q-1)$, then $p$ is a factor of $Q-(Q-1)=1$. The only positive
integer factor of $1$ is $1$.